# Incorrect Duration returned by GetMusicPropertiesAsync on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to build a music picker to build a playlist in my app, I select files from the media library with

```
await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)
```

and then select the music properties for each file with:

```
var info = await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(async f => new 
    { file = f, m = await f.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync() }));
```

For some reason the Duration property is totally off for my media - it's actually a 10000 times smaller number, so for a media file that has duration of 1:10:02 (4202 seconds) it reports duration of 0.420224 seconds.

The real number of milliseconds for the media is stored in Ticks for the timespan.
so to get the true duration of the media I have to recalculate the duration as

```
item.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(item.Duration.Ticks)
```

Am I missing something in the documentation? Docs for [MusicProperties.Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties.duration) state that it `Gets the duration of the song in milliseconds.` and it's a `TimeSpan`, so is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was found this bug too. Possible solution is loading file from path (but may be slower):

```
StorageFile fileShadow = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Path);
var musicProps = await fileShadow.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
var duration = musicProps.Duration;//Valid duration
```